# ASPNETCORE reverse proxy to merge an existing application into a new Angular SPA

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I have an existing website with URLS like this

```
/ 
/product1
/product2
/store/*
/customerservice
/faq
```

I want to replace my site with a brand new Angular SPA application hosted at `/`, starting with a new homepage, new product pages, and then gradually migrate over the other pages as time permits.

So right now I'd want `/store` to proxy transparently to the existing website in a different application pool, but without any kind of HTTP redirect.

I am hosting the application in IIS on ASPNETCORE 2.1 and trying to find the best approach to do this. Getting confused about whether I need to use:

- Reverse proxy middleware
- Branched pipeline in ASPNETCORE
- Some kind of reverse proxy in IIS
- Set up a proxy.conf file
- I don't want to do a subdomain, but that's an easy option

I need to tell Angular to hit the server for these routes, and bypass its own routing mechanism.

Surprised how little information I'm finding on how to do this since I would have thought it was a very common need.

Comment: Angular will automatically make normal server requests if you use normal links instead of router links. And if you’re hosting through ASP.NET Core, just make sure that the MVC middleware runs before the SPA middleware and then all routes that still exist in MVC will run properly.

Comment: Ah ok that makes the angular side easier :) although I’d like to maybe set it in the routing file somehow so I only need to change it in one place. But which middleware should I use?

Comment: Just the normal MVC and SPA middlewares. Look at the default 2.1 SPA template to see how that should look like.